# Physics simulation examples

Tags: c#, physics

im starting to study physics simulation and i was hoping i could get code examples... anyone knows where i can find some? i would love it in c#... but any other would be fine too...

Comment: You're looking for the actual source?

Comment: complete source code would be nicer... but i settle for comprehensive snipets too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Farseer](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) is a good, open-source (C#) 2D physics engine. Diving straight into source codes for physics engines may be a bit overwhelming if you don't have much experience with programming physics in general. MetanetSoftware have a [couple of good tutorials](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) regarding collision detection.

Edit: Farseer was renamed and moved to: [VelcroPhysics](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look around http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/  and http://www.ode.org/

Bullet and ODE are open source, though I can't say where precisely that code is.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/checkout